# AngularFireDatabase list function not being called on ios ionic

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I am trying to do the most basic retrieval with Ionic and `AngularFireDatabase`. My code is as follows:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SignInPage } from '../signin/signin';
import { FeedUser } from '../feeduser/feeduser';
import { FeedStylist } from '../feedstylist/feedstylist';
import { Keyboard } from '@ionic-native/keyboard';
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';


@Component({
  selector: 'page-sign-up',
  templateUrl: 'signup.html'
})
export class SignUpPage {
  stylist: boolean;
  user: boolean;
  items: FirebaseListObservable<any>;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public keyboard: Keyboard, public af: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.items = af.list('/test');
    console.log(this.items);
  }

  ...
```

There are no errors, but nothing happens - the console message is never logged...not even null (if its not retrieving the items).

I am using Ionic 3.5.0, and iOS 10. This problem only happens on iOS device, it works in the browser. Thanks

Comment: it seems `constructor` of `SignUpPage` is never runned based on `the console message is never logged`. you should confirm whether your routing is working.

Answer (score 2):

`af.list('/test')` return observable so it will take some time to resolve value and return result but in your code your immediate accessing observable  value before resolving observable.

you need subscribe observable and access value

example

```
 this.items = af.list('/test');
   this.items.subscribe(value=> {
        console.log(this.items);
    });
```

Comment: thanks - ill try it soon - im wondering...do you have to do this because of ionic? in the angularfire2 docs it never mentions this...still getting to know ionic...is `subscribe` something i would use in other places too? would it just be used for network requests?

Comment: I think your new to angular or Ionic. I will recommend to start learning observable before jumping to Ionic. yes you can use subscribe in other components and you need unsubscribe  while destroying components

Comment: ok...when i use your code it cant find `snapshots` variable...i changed it to `value` but yah you are right i am knew to observables and subscribe/unsubscribe

Comment: after a 10-15 seconds an error pops up that says "Runtime Error: Network Error"

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/3-retrieving-data-as-lists.md all the way at the bottom there is an example with the `preserveSnapshot` option...is this it? also the docs on that page dont say anything about needing to subscribe when using list

Comment: sorry I gave bad example. i update answer.In your case you no need use `Snapshot`

Comment: it didn't work, according to the docs i dont think you have to use subscribe...the app loads - it waits about 10-15 seconds and then an ionic error pops up that says "Runtime Error: Network Error".

Comment: i tried something and got a new error: i did this `this.items = af.list('test');
    this.items.subscribe(value=> {
      //console.log(value);
      value.forEach(item => {
        console.log('Item:', item);
      });
      //console.log(this.items);
    });` and i get this error message `error opening ws message: {"category":"console","type":"log","data":["Item:",{"$value":"list"}]} ` i think something deeper with networking might be going on.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what ended up working:

```
this.items = af.list('/test');
this.items.subscribe(items => items.forEach(item => { 
  console.log(item.$value);
}));
```